# Sudo and su simultaneously?

Tags: sudo, su

To switch between users sometimes  `sudo su newuser` is used.

What is meaning of `sudo su` together?

Can anyone tell exactly how they both command together work?

Answer (score 3):

- You need superuser power to switch users. Hence the `sudo`
- `su` is the command to "switch user" and the name behind it what you switch to, where nothing behind it makes you "root".
- `sudo -i` is preferred over `sudo su` when switching to "root" since log files are then updated with the user login name and not "root".

Answer (score 0):

When changing the user with `su` you need to know the password of the user you are changing to.

Using `sudo su - <username>` does not require the password of the user you are changing to, but only your own password for `sudo`. With `sudo` you effectively run `su` as `root` who is allowed to change the user without knowing the password of the user.